# Ubuntu 14.04 does not allow changing default calculator?

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, default-programs, calculator

I created a custom shortcut in `Keyboard->Shortcuts` and set it opens `qalculator` app.

[image]

Then I assigned to it the keyboard Calculator key. Ubuntu asked me if I want to replace the original app and I confirmed it.

But now, nothing happens when I press the keyboard calculator key! I even changed the command from `qalculator` to `/usr/bin/qalculate` or `/usr/share/qalculate`, but the app does not open at all.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in unity-settings-daemon. I have filed it with them: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-settings-daemon/+bug/1399132

As a workaround you can edit the settings manually with dconf Editor. To install it run `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`.

You can find your custom shortcut under `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybindings` and change the `binding` value to `XF86Calculator`

Refer to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Keybindings